# Counting the number of pictures appearing in a pdf

Tags: pdf, pictures

Is there a way to count the number of times that the exact same picture (png file) appeared in a pdf file?

Comment: I very much doubt there is.

Comment: Me too. I tried searching online but I can't find anything.

Comment: It seems to be a very specific usage case for which I doubt anyone thought about it before. And this doesn't even take into consideration the technical aspects which I imagine aren't easy to overcome. Yes, with a PDF editor (not reader) you should be able to "see" individual elements like images and eventually somewhere find the list of those elements but other than that...